# I am showing or I am seeing?

Tags: grammar, continuous-aspect

When something is displayed on computer screen ( e.g a list or names of servers etc) people use "I am showing the below list" is this correct ?

I use "I am seeing the below list". I observed people residing in USA use "showing" can any please help me understand what is correct usage.

Comment: "Show" means display for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you are trying to say that *you are the person who has displayed the list for others to see*, or if you are participating in a conversation and *wish to notify the others that you are able to see the list*.

The phrase "I am showing" as you implied seems to mean "My computer screen is showing me.." or "I have manipulated my computer in such a way that I am showing (myself) the list."

Comment: It's not often that I upvote an unsupported answer, but I think the major dictionaries need to include the sense you mention; it's a neologism. I'd go with a less marked 'I am showing ...' = 'What I am seeing on the [computer screen etc] is ...'.

Comment: is it wrong if I use "I am seeing" e.g  I am seeing below list?

Comment: No, that's fine.